# Option to hide columns completely on an extnet GridPanel

Tags: user-controls, ext.net, gridpanel

I was using this based on a condition

```
GridPanelName.ColumnModel.SetHidden([ColumnIndex], true)
```

while I was working on something else, I noticed that when I click on the sorting menu arrow on a column header, under the columns I can put a tick next to the "hidden" column and it becomes visible again.

Is there a way for not showing columns except hidden, someway a curious user can not walk around ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on client side:

```
<ext:Column ID="ColumnID" runat="server" Text="ID" DataIndex="ID" Width="100" Visible="false" />
```